# Is the question about electric versus fossil-fuelled vehicles on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

[How do hybrid cars reduce carbon emissions (wouldn't they just transfer fuel emissions to electricity consumption?)](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/2696/100) is probably the furthest we've strayed into the mechanical engineering aspects of climate change mitigation, and that seemed worth a discussion about site scope.

Where is our scope boundary here?

Answer (score 10):

*(This is just the first flash of ideas I have on that. A discussion should probably follow, and I'm 100% open to it.)*

In my opinion, it is **off-topic**, since it is not in scope of any earth scientists to be able to discuss the CO2 trace of combustion vs hybrid vs purely electrical cars.

We can discuss how much the emissions from car traffic influence the climate, but for such question to be relevant on this site, the question itself should IMHO contain the relevant data, i.e., what is the CO2 trace.

Such question could be asked on:

- [Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) and this has been done: [Does a car with a hybrid engine and Lithium batteries pollute more than a car with conventional technology?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/351)
- maybe on [Mechanics.SE](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/), but I am not 100% sure since I don't know the policies of that site, and it would certainly use some insight of their moderators
- then [Sustainable Living.SE](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com) -- it seems that questions related to trace-less car operation would be on-topic there, however, I'm not sure if the question in question is enough about sustainability to fit there. Surely not all "green" questions do.

Comment: Yes definitely off topic! imho

Comment: I agree that it's off topic here, as I can't think of any field that would describe itself as "earth science" that would answer it. I feel that it would be on-topic, and probably get a good answer, on sustainability.SE.

Comment: Many users may not dislike this question, because environmental protection techniques are quite popular among earth scientists. But it is off topic. The only site, which I can imagine for this question, is http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60453/engineering.